# How can i deploy telegram bot?

Tags: python, telegram

I've just started learning how to crate telegram bots, i already have some programming experience so I was managed to create and launch a couple on my local PC. But I've faced some serious troubles deploying bots on some remote or cloud service. I have deployed my bot on heroku, but it stops working very often for no reason, at least i can't find any. How can I deploy my bots to the internet for free? I'm not seeking for commercial benefits, for now i just want to test myself.

Comment: Thats how Heroku works, I'm guessing you're not using a paid tier so its dyno's won't be running 24/7.

Also, "it stops working" isn't much to help diagnose.

Comment: is there any way to run my bot 24/7 for free?

Comment: A bot doesn't have to run in the cloud. Since it uses an HTTP API to talk to telegram it can run from any system that has internet access. Get yourself a Rasberry Pi or so and you should be able to run your bot at home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I dealt with this kind of problem. Fist this is my sample code:

```
    while True:
        try:
            bot.polling(none_stop=True,timeout=60,interval=10)
            break
        except Exception as e:
            logging.exception(e)
            sleep(10)
            continue
```

Note that everything is wrapped in `try` `except`. Why because `polling()` method can give exceptions for instance `TimeoutError` and many more so you need to log them to see what is happening and then write your own handler.